# Using subdomains in NestJS with Fastify Adapter?

Tags: nestjs, fastify, nestjs-fastify

The [docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/controllers#sub-domain-routing) state that Fastify doesn't support nested routers, however they do support a [Route Config](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/performance#route-config) which in theory should allow me to use [constraints](https://fastify.dev/docs/latest/Reference/Routes/#host-constraints) to limit a route to a sub domain, such as the following:

```js
import { Controller, Get } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { RouteConfig } from '@nestjs/platform-fastify';

@Controller()
export class AppController {
  constructor(private readonly appService: AppService) {}

  @RouteConfig({
    constraints: { host: 'admin.example.com' },
  })
  @Get()
  getHello(): string {
    return this.appService.getHello();
  }
}
```

This doesn't work in practice however, and seems to resolve to the same route regardless of top-level or subdomain resolution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer might be a bit late, but my PR to add this feature was merged only today.

In previous versions of `@nestjs/platform-fastify` (< `v10.3`) you wouldn't be able to use `@RouteConfig` as that only implements Fastitfy's [route config](https://fastify.dev/docs/latest/Reference/Routes/#config) feature.

If possible, update your `@nestjs/platform-fastify` to a recent version (`>= v10.3.0`) and use `@RouteConstraints` decorator:

```
import { Controller, Get } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { RouteConstraints } from '@nestjs/platform-fastify';

@Controller()
export class AppController {
  constructor(private readonly appService: AppService) {}

  @RouteConstraints({
    host: 'admin.example.com',
  })
  @Get()
  getHello(): string {
    return this.appService.getHello();
  }
}
```

References:

- https://github.com/nestjs/nest/releases/tag/v10.3.0
- https://github.com/fastify/fastify/releases/tag/v4.25.0
- https://github.com/nestjs/docs.nestjs.com/pull/2926

*Thank you for pointing to this issue and giving me an opportunity to do some OSS contributions :)*